# Spatial query that does not split objects

Tags: qgis

I’m a novice user of QGIS. I have searched this site and failed to find an ability to split a layer into new layers based on a secondary input.

I have a layer of buildings with no attributes. I want to devide them into new layers/files by zip code. I have a layer with zip codes. Both are in the same CRS. However when I use split or intersection operations it will cut the house in half if it crosses the zip code. Is there a way to retain the integrity of the house and have it duplicated into both zip code layers?

Answer (score 2):

If you make a query using **intersects** operator your buildings objects will be duplicated as many times as they intersect zip code areas.

In the other hand if you use **the centroid of the building** in your query your building will be associated with only one zip code area.

In any case a query can return (among other things) the geometry of your objects (and eventually duplicate objects ...)

So an answer to your question is building the right query in the **DB_manager** of QGIS. Something like :

```
select building.geometry,zip_code.id from building, zip_code
where st_intersects (building.geometry, zip_code.geometry)
```

Adapt it according to your data structure.

*To write your query go to : Database / Database Manager / Database Manager then Virtual Layers / Qgis Layers ...*

Comment: Did that help ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Join attributes by location` tool to create a copy of the building layer with zip code values added.

- Choose the option to "Create separate feature for each located feature (one-to-many)". This option will create a copy of each building that falls into multiple zip codes.

[image]

Use the `Split Vector Layer` tool to split the new layer based on the zip code field.

[image]

Notes:

- The tools mentioned here are available through the Processing Toolbox.
- The default output type of most processing tools is a temporary layer, which will be deleted when you close the QGIS project. Be sure to save any temporary layers that you want to keep before closing the project.